# How to wait until loading chrome tab's spinning wheel stops?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Is there an event to detect when the tab's loading spinning wheel on chrome stops ?
I tried:

> networkidle0, networkidle2, domcontentloaded

with no success

ex of page when I need to wait until it is loaded: 
https://www.translatetheweb.com/?from=&to=fr&ref=SERP&refd=www.bing.com&dl=fr&rr=UC&a=https%3a%2f%2fwww.247freepoker.com%2f

For now I use a 30 seconds waitFor

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You could try to check the frame's `_lifecycleEvents` manually.

This function will resolve when that frame gets the `networkIdle` cycle event.

```js
function waitForFrameLoaded(frame) {
    let fulfill;
    const promise = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);
    frame._frameManager.on('Events.FrameManager.LifecycleEvent', checkFrame)
    checkFrame(frame);
    return promise;

    function checkFrame(eventFrame) {
        if (eventFrame == frame && eventFrame._lifecycleEvents.has('networkIdle'))
        fulfill(frame);
    }
}
```

With that function, you could do something like this:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://www.translatetheweb.com/?from=&to=fr&ref=SERP&refd=www.bing.com&dl=fr&rr=UC&a=https%3a%2f%2fwww.247freepoker.com%2f");
const frameElement = await page.waitForSelector('#frmTgt')
const frame = await frameElement.contentFrame();
await waitForFrameLoaded(frame);
```